How can I solve FileNotFoundError when installing pypeit?
I'm trying to install PypeIt using pip in VSCode and I'm getting the following error:
  Collecting pypeit
  Using cached pypeit-1.16.0.tar.gz (163.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main   
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe6by9g5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe6by9g5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe6by9g5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup       
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 63, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe6by9g5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\extension_helpers\_setup_helpers.py", line 63, in get_extensions
          for setuppkg in iter_setup_packages(srcdir, packages):
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe6by9g5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\extension_helpers\_setup_helpers.py", line 159, in iter_setup_packages
          module = import_file(setup_package, name=packagename + ".setup_package")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qe6by9g5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\extension_helpers\_utils.py", line 136, in import_file  
          loader.exec_module(mod)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File ".\pypeit\bspline\setup_package.py", line 58, in <module>
        File ".\pypeit\bspline\setup_package.py", line 36, in check_for_openmp
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\aqbal\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried installing it through conda, installing all of the necessary dependencies, changed to conda, downloaded the github... Absolutely nothing is working and I don't really understand what the error means.

The error is from _winapi.CreateProcess(), which means it's trying to run an external program, but couldn't find it.  Either the program is not installed at all, or it wasn't found in your PATH environment.  (In other similar questions that program is often ffmpeg, but I don't know if that is the case here.)

The function which fails is trying to run a C compiler so I'm guessing you don't have one.
https://github.com/pypeit/PypeIt/issues/1605 appears to be the same issue. The reporter ended up working around the issue by switching to WSL, where gcc is available out of the box.

Certainly, installing a C compiler on Windows should work as well. I'm not competent to instruct you on which one to install or what to do when Windows inevitably fails for other reasons anyway.
